Java ThreadPoolExecutor: How can it ensure the state check in execute() method is safe?
Basic:
// this.a is a shared variable.
AtomicInteger a = this.a;
int x = a.get();

In a multi-threaded condition, we cannot ensure that x is 1 because some other thread may call something like a.getAndIncrement() just before we load the stored value in a to x, which cause the final result of x to be 2.
So, in ThreadPoolExecutor:
public void execute(Runnable command) {
    if (command == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    int c = ctl.get();
    if (workerCountOf(c) < corePoolSize) {
        if (addWorker(command, true))
            return;
        c = ctl.get();
    }
    if (isRunning(c) && workQueue.offer(command)) {
        int recheck = ctl.get();
        if (!isRunning(recheck) && remove(command))
            reject(command);
        else if (workerCountOf(recheck) == 0)
            addWorker(null, false);
    }
    else if (!addWorker(command, false))
        reject(command);
}

in the recheck routine:
    if (isRunning(c) && workQueue.offer(command)) {
        int recheck = ctl.get();
        if (!isRunning(recheck) && remove(command))
            reject(command);
        else if (workerCountOf(recheck) == 0)
            addWorker(null, false);
    }

we read from AtomicInteger ctl and load it into recheck. But it also may be changed by other threads at any time. Is there some mechanism which make this recheck to be absolutely reliable? Or do we just need to consider most of the cases?
Below is the occurrence I've talked about which is less possible to happen:
    if (isRunning(c) && workQueue.offer(command)) {   // RUNNING
        int recheck = ctl.get();                      // RUNNING
        if (!isRunning(recheck) && remove(command))   // RUNNING
            reject(command);
        else if (workerCountOf(recheck) == 0)         // RUNNING and workerCount is 0
            // SHUTDOWN by other thread
            addWorker(null, false);                   // SO?
    }

My thought: ThreadPools can't be restarted, so the state transmation can't be SHUTDOWN -> RUNNING. The question then become: if we shutdown the pool while rechecking, and it failed to load the instant state into recheck, what will happen?
I noticed that when the Pool wants to add a new Worker, it will check the current state again and acquire the mainLock before adding the worker into workers. So:

Is the lock that make the state control of Thread Pool safe?
Is ctl a variable that is placed in front and used to block most concurrent issues?
Is the reason for the ctl variable to exist to avoid excessive acquisition of global locks?


I'm not sure I understand the intent or what the goal is here.  If you need a value that can be read reliably, don't share it.  If a is a local variable, you don't have to worry about other threads changing it.  If you want single threaded semantics, don't let other threads change your variables.  So, given that you seem to want semantics that preclude multi-threading, why are you sharing a in the first place?

@markspace My mistake. a is supposed to be a variable shared by multiple threads. like ctl in ThreadPoolExecutor.

That still doesn't tell me why you are sharing something that you then say the sharing is causing problems.  What are you actually trying to do? What is the goal?
